# AngularJS - initialization inside $watch which depends on two models

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an async JS function (i.e. a http request, but a request, this is a direct call to my JavaFX app through Java bindings) which returns some result and puts it into the model attrubute, `modelAttribute1`.

I have also a `$watch` function on some other model `modelAttribute2`, which uses this first model, i.e.:

```
scope.$watch(modelAttribute2, function(newVal, oldVal){
    scope.$apply(function(){
        // newVal is correct, but modelAttribute1 is not yet initialized!
        scope.scriptText = loadFile(newVal, scope[modelAttribute1]); 
    });
});
```

The problem is that this watch expression is being executed before I get the result from Java.

So is there an approach for this like creating a promise and listening for it's computation to finish?

Comment: writing a promise inside the success function may solve the problem ?? i guess ??

Comment: I can't say if I don't try, but I can't do this, because in my case I have not yet implemented a support for callback functions :-)

Comment: The first call to $watch happens when you setup the watch with oldVal and newVal undefined. You should build a check for that like `if(newVal){...}`.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I'm initializing with `ng-init`, this is why `newVal` is defined for the first call. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with promises:

```
var d1 = $q.defer(), d2 = $q.defer();

scope.$watch("modelAttribute1", function(newVal) {
    if( newVal != null ) d1.resolve(newVal);
});
scope.$watch("modelAttribute2", function(newVal) {
    if( newVal != null ) d2.resolve(newVal);
});

$q.all([d1, d2]).then(function(arr) {
    // here scope.modelAttribute1 = arr[0],
    //      scope.modelAttribute2 = arr[1]
    scope.scriptText = loadFile(arr[1], arr[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since  http request is async we can wrap it with promise  like:

```
   var data = //...<from http>
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   deferred.resolve(data);
   deferred.then(function(arr) {   
      modelAttribute1 = arr;
    });
```

*as a side note*:

I don't know if you use deep watch, set flag `true`:

```
scope.$watch(modelAttribute2, function(newVal, oldVal){
    scope.$apply(function(){
        // newVal is correct, but modelAttribute1 is not yet initialized!
        scope.scriptText = loadFile(newVal, scope[modelAttribute1]); 
    });
}, true);
```